# Pixel Size in WCS2

Tags: geoserver, ogr, wcs

i'm using a WCS2 POST query to get RAW data from a Geoserver GIS Server, but i need to get this info with a given pixel size (larger than the original data in the server) and i'm not being able to do it.

My current XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wcs:GetCoverage xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0 ../../wcsAll.xsd"
  service="WCS" version="2.0.1">
  <wcs:CoverageId>auraview__ndvi1</wcs:CoverageId>

    <gml:RectifiedGrid>
        <gml:offsetVector srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">0.0 9E-5</gml:offsetVector>
        <gml:offsetVector srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">-9E-5 0.0</gml:offsetVector>
    </gml:RectifiedGrid>

  <wcs:DimensionTrim>
  <wcs:Dimension>Lat</wcs:Dimension>
  <wcs:TrimLow>36.9601</wcs:TrimLow>
  <wcs:TrimHigh>36.9674</wcs:TrimHigh>
  </wcs:DimensionTrim>

  <wcs:DimensionTrim>
  <wcs:Dimension>Long</wcs:Dimension>
  <wcs:TrimLow>-120.2739</wcs:TrimLow>
  <wcs:TrimHigh>-120.2652</wcs:TrimHigh>
  </wcs:DimensionTrim>

  <wcs:DimensionSlice>
  <wcs:Dimension>elevation</wcs:Dimension>
  <wcs:SlicePoint>279</wcs:SlicePoint>
  </wcs:DimensionSlice>

  <wcs:DimensionSlice>
  <wcs:Dimension>time</wcs:Dimension>

  <wcs:SlicePoint>2017-01-27T00:00:00Z</wcs:SlicePoint>
  </wcs:DimensionSlice>

</wcs:GetCoverage>
```

In that file 9E-5 is the pixel size I need (in degrees as it is EPSG 4326). But it is not working, and i get a 1E-5 pixel size that is the datasource default.

Comment: What WCS profiles are reported as supported in the WCS GetCapabilities?

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered slice and trim operations in WCS 2 will only ever return the raw data (or the closest approximation if you do a reprojection).

To change pixel size I think you need to have support for the scaling profile:

```
<ows:Profile>
  http://www.opengis.net/spec/WCS_service-extension_scaling/1.0/conf/scaling
</ows:Profile>
```

ref [OGC® WCS Interface Standard - Scaling Extension, version 1.0.0](https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/12-039)